# ffmpeg: Unable to recode subtitle event

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode subtitles with german umlauts into a video file - after much research on ffmpeg I came up with this:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i in.avi -i in1.srt -sub_charenc UTF-8 -i in2.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 -metadata:s:s:0 language=english -metadata:s:s:1 language=german output.mp4
```

...but it tells me it can't do it, because

```
Unable to recode subtitle event "und gehõngt." from UTF-8 to UTF-8.5x
```

Error while decoding stream #2:0: Illegal byte sequence

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this, and how to do it correctly?

Many thanks!

Comment: Provide a link to `in1.srt`.

Comment: I kinda figured it out, but only 'kinda'... The above example is encoded as such: 'und gehängt' = 756e 6420 6765 68e4 6e67 74 - so the umlaut 'ä' is e4, so that would point to UTF-16, but it is encoded in only one byte...? (I'm sorry, but I'm new not only to character encoding but also to this forum here - I can't have a newline in this editor, because pressing return just posts the whole comment? weird... :)

Comment: here's the srt-file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00609002665547998363

Comment: You can try `-sub_charenc ISO-8859-1` (from output of `file in2.srt`) or use `iconv` or some other tool to change the character encoding of `in2.srt`.

Comment: yep, that totally worked, thanks...! and wow, this whole thing really seems to be a can of worms... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to insert subtitles in a video or at least they are the ones I know.

- The first is to insert a **stream** into the container.
- The second is to **burn** them in the video.

Advantages:

- As **Stream** You can enable or disable subtitles.
- If you **Burn the subtitles** they will be available for all players without the need to configure anything.

Disadvantages:

- As **Stream** you need the video player have support to detect these streams (Subtitles), Most have it so this option is the most recommended.
- If you **Burn** them It will be impossible to delete subtitles or deactivate them.

This is the command to add subtitles as **STREAMS**:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i input.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy -map 1 -c:s:0 mov_text output.mp4
```

> Note: You must specify the correct type of subtitle encoding and replace it instead of ISO-8859-1.

To know the correct encoding of your subtitles, execute the following command:

```
file your_subtitle.srt
```

This will print something like this 
your_subtitle.srt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators

This is the command to **Burn Subtitles**:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=sub_file.srt output.mp4
```

For more information about Streams, codec and FFMPEG visit:

[FFMPEG Basic Course](https://slhck.info/ffmpeg-encoding-course/#/)
[FFMPEG Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)
[FFMPEG Man](https://skeleton.freeze.sh/man/ffmpeg.html)

Comment: The stream variant of substitles should distinguish between _bitmap_ subtitles and _text_ subtitles (.srt). Just a suggestion for improving your answer, because text subtitles are differently (as text) encoded in the stream.

Comment: thank you i will study that because i din't know the difference

Answer (score 0):

Determine character encoding of file:

```
$ file in2.srt 
in2.srt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Now use `-sub_charenc`:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i in.avi -i in1.srt -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i in2.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 -metadata:s:s:0 language=english -metadata:s:s:1 language=german output.mp4
```

Note the inclusion of the `-1` part in `ISO-8859-1`.

Or convert character encoding with `iconv`, or some other tool, to utf8 and then use `ffmpeg` without needing `-sub_charenc`:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf8 in2.srt > in3.srt
```